# How can I use a template in data-content of bootstrap popover in angular

Tags: angularjs, popover

Hi I need to show a popover over an image which I am doing using map tag.

The issue is on popover i need to show a form but I am unable to render a html page in data-content of boot strap.

I made attempts like
https://plnkr.co/edit/CBhLV7?p=preview

directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('iconPopover',['$templateCache',function($templateCache){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    template: $templateCache.get('form.html')
  }
}])
```

//index.html

```
< img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/bb/54/8b/bb548b6fa0862e92302c4ba4fb1a85ed.jpg" usemap="#mymap" />

< map name="mymap">
  < div style="border:1px solid green; position:absolute; width:60px; height:60px; 
  left:{{marker.XPos}}px; top:{{marker.YPos}};"
    data-html="true"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-trigger="focus"
    data-content="<icon-popover></icon-popover>"
    ng-repeat="marker in markers"
    ng-click="showPopover($event)"
  >
     <area 
    shape="{{marker.shape}}" 
    coords="{{marker.coords}}" 
    href="#" />

  </ div>
```